# Sending data from flash to node.js server with socket.io

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a simple socket.io based server in node.js that listens to a socket in port 81 (for example)
I have no problem connecting and passing data between clients written in Javascript
But after a lot of tries I can't get my Flash app to connect to the server and pass data to it
(I found some examples in the web - but all of them are flex based and use classes that aren't parts of the basic AS3 libraries)

when I'm trying to connect to the socket using a XMLSocket - I get Security Sandbox Violation Error - I know that I need to load the policy file (which suppose to be available using socket.io)
but I can't manage to do it

this is my flash code:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://127.0.0.1:81/crossdomain.xml");
socket = new XMLSocket("127.0.0.1", 81);
socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);  
socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);  
socket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityEvent);
socket.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, onData);
```

and the server side code is

```
var app = require('http').createServer(function (req, res) {...})
   , io = require('socket.io').listen(app, { log: true })
   , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(81);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("connection "+socket.id);
    socket.on("message",function(data){
        console.log("data: "+data);
    });
    socket.on("data",function(d){
         console.log('data from flash: ',d);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function (socket) {
        console.log("disconnect");
    });
});
```

and my crossdomain.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Do you have a policy file being served from your node.js server? Typically you have a file called ["crossdomain.xml" at the root of your site](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html#main_Cross_domain_policy_files).

Comment: I have, but still the flash throwing an error: `Request for resource at xmlsocket://127.0.0.1:81 by requestor from XXXXX.swf is denied due to lack of policy file permissions`

Comment: Your `loadPolicyFile()` call is not pointed at a policy file. Try `Security.loadPolicyFile("http://127.0.0.1:81/crossdomain.xml")`.

Comment: tried it - it is loading the policy file but I still have the error from my previous comment (before I added `Security.loadPolicyFile(...)` I had another error - which means that the flash can read the policy file, but the policy is not permitting enough

Comment: changed to as3 code to the updated + added the crossdomain.xml content. maybe the problem is there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For our last project, we used [FlashSocket.IO](https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO), worked like a charm.

We had to do minor adaptions on the server-side (i.e. make sure socket.io listens for the policyfile on port 843 rather than 10843) and activate the flashsocket transport, but the communication was a breeze.

```
io.configure(function() {
  io.set('transports', ['websocket','flashsocket']);
  io.set('flash policy port', 843);
});
```

NOTE: this configuration requires node.js to be run as root!

Comment: actually I have already found this, but apparently in current versions of Node.js the privacy policy socket is not turned on by default - which I solved by adding `io.set('transports', ['websocket', 'flashsocket']);` - Thankyou anyway :)

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right...i was missing out that the flashsocket transport is disabled by default, sorry. Adjusted my answer accordingly

Comment: by the way - this library doesn't work without the flex libraries (mx) 
https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO/blob/0.7.x/src/com/pnwrain/flashsocket/FlashSocket.as
it uses `mx.collections.ArrayCollection` and `mx.utils.URLUtil`

Comment: Yeah, my collegue had to hack around a bit with the source to make it independant from flex. But i can't give you any details since he's on vacation :/

Comment: I did it also by adding the `URLUtil` source code to my project :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093429/how-to-fix-this-probably-cross-domain-policy-error-using-flash-socket-io-and/14093590#14093590) solution (you need to setup the socket policy server in addition to the game server on the port 843)

BTW: when you use socket always use url like `xmlsocket://host:port` (for port 843 flash loads policy file automatically) rather than `http://host:port` witch is only for http requests.