# Socket IO and policy file Internet Explorer

Tags: node.js, flash, internet-explorer, socket.io

Im having a problem using Socket.io on Internet Explorer.
After some seconds conected i got this error message:

```
cannot connect to Web Socket server at ws://example.com.br:80/socket.io/... (SecurityError) make sure the server is running and Flash socket policy file is correctly placed.
```

I have done some researchs about what is a policy file, but any of those could help me.

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

```
/*** IO ***/
var
  options     = { retry_max_delay: config.app.redis.retryMaxDelay },
  redis       = require('redis'),
  client      = redis.createClient(config.app.redis.port, config.app.redis.host, options),
  Connector   = require('./lib/Connector'),
  Helper      = require('./lib/Helper'),
  io          = require('socket.io').listen(server),
  Social      = require('./lib/service/Social'),
  Terms       = require('./lib/service/Terms'),
  UserChecker = require('./lib/service/UserChecker'),
  users       = {};

io.configure(function() {
  'use strict';

  io.set('browser client gzip'         , false);
  io.set('browser client minification' , false);
  io.set('close timeout'               , 60);
  io.set('heartbeat interval'          , 25);
  io.set('heartbeat timeout'           , 60);
  io.set('log level'                   , config.socket.logLevel);
});

io.set('transports', [
  'websocket',
  'flashsocket',
  'htmlfile',
  'xhr-polling',
  'jsonp-polling'
]);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  'use strict';

  logger.debug('Socket (' + socket.id + ') connected.');

  client.incr('chat:connection');

  var
    connector   = new Connector(socket),
    social      = new Social(config),
    terms       = new Terms(config),
    userChecker = new UserChecker(connector, socket);

  function send(response, bind, callback) {
    if (bind) {
      connector.addEventListeners();
    }

    if (callback) {
      callback(response);
    }
  }

  socket.on('join', function(message, callback) {
    var
      json = Helper.toJSON(message),
      skip = userChecker.shouldSkip(json, config);

    if (skip) {
      var data = userChecker.skip(users, json);

      users = data.users;

      return send(data.response, true, callback);
    }

    social.check(json, function(response, access) {
      if (!access) {
        return send(response, false, callback);
      }

      terms.check(json, function(response) {
        send(response, true, callback);
      });
    });
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    users = userChecker.disconnect(users);
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: It seems your Socket.IO server isn't serving up the files needed for the Flash transport.  I'm not sure why... you would have to actually show us your code and tell us what version of Socket.IO you're using.  Note that you can disable the Flash transport to get around this problem, but I wouldn't.

Comment: Hello Brad, I was thinking about disable the Flash transport but i guess not a good idea.
The socket.io version that im using is `0.9.17`.
I also noticed that my application is running in a domain like `sub.example.com` and my socket ate `sub1.example.com`. Does it influence something?

Comment: Socket.IO can work cross-domain without issue.  Show your code.  You might also consider switching to a newer version of Socket.IO.

Comment: Im considering to upgrade to the newer version of Socket.IO as soon as I can :)

Here's part of the code:
http://pastebin.com/z34xxxes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix this (probably) cross domain policy error using Flash, Socket.IO and NodeJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093429/how-to-fix-this-probably-cross-domain-policy-error-using-flash-socket-io-and)