# RESTful DELETE with AS3 using as3httpclient

Tags: actionscript-3, rest

A RESTful DELETE request from as3 using as3httpclient works fine on a local file system in flash. But when deployed in a browser from a server the request doesn't happen. What is the reason? Are there any limitations? Is there a work around for this problem?

Comment: as3httpclient uses _Socket_ for connection, so you have to setup a socket policy server, check out that answser for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093429/how-to-fix-this-probably-cross-domain-policy-error-using-flash-socket-io-and/14093590#14093590